# how to make widgets float over each other in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, widget

How to make these two (shown in the picture) float over the card in that way (aligning slightly out of the card border).

[the requested design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCmkq.png)

this is the widget code

Card(
shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
),
elevation: 3,
//color: Colors.orange,
child: Container(width: 140, height: 140,
child: Image.asset('assets/c1.png',
scale:1,),
),
),

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow! Stack overflow is a platform for getting answers to your code related questions. We generally require you to upload some of the work you have done including the code that you have wrote. We do not provide code from scratch for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below was used to create this. The red card can be an image instead and positioned accordingly.

[image]

```
 Stack(
      overflow: Overflow.visible,
      children: [
        Positioned(
            top: 10,
            right: -20,
            child: Card(
              elevation: 3,
              color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.5),
              child: Container(width: 30, height: 50),
            )),
        Card(
          elevation: 1,
          color: Colors.purple,
          child: Container(
            width: 250,
            height: 250,
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
            top: 20,
            left: -20,
            child: Card(
              elevation: 3,
              color: Colors.orange,
          child: Container(width: 80, height: 80),
        )),

        Positioned(
            top: 20,
            right: -20,
            child: Card(
              elevation: 3,
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Container(width: 120, height: 50),
            ))
      ],
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the Stack class - looks like you want to arrange widgets on top of each other.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html